# Is it possible to set/change in Windows the FOLDER(not file) Security Permissions with Java?

Tags: java, windows

Does anybody know if it is possible to set/change in Windows the FOLDER(not file) Security Permissions with Java? In Windows it can be done like this: right click on folder -> Properties -> Security(tab) -> Select a user/group -> click edit.

Comment: That doesn't sound OS agnostic to me.  Java doesn't tie into operating systems that way by design.

Comment: Note that changing the permissions for a folder is typically exactly the same process as changing the permissions for a file.